# mariadb-connector-odbc v3.1.20 "t_nobigint" unit test fails for big endian

Tags: mysql, mariadb, odbc, ubuntu-22.04, endian-firewall

In mariadb-connector-odbc v3.1.20 under test/types.c, unit test t_nobigint fails for big endian s390x. I am pretty sure it's because of the way hex decimal(byte conversion) took place in big endian. I tried executing same test in little endian it passes there. That says, there is nothing wrong with way unit test case is written.

Now I am not sure, how to solve this? What should be the fix? I've no shame to say that I am a noob on this.

Here is the test case: https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-odbc/blob/3.1.20/test/types.c#L292

Below is the error log

```
DSN=maodbc_test;UID=root;PWD={********};PORT=3306;DATABASE=test;OPTION=67108866;SERVER=localhost;NOBIGINT=1
/home/linux1/workspace/mariadb-connector-odbc/test/types.c 327: 0xFFFFFFFF0000000F(-4294967281)!=id(68719476735)
```

And below is my system configuration.

> Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS; Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-56-generic;
> Architecture: s390x

Installation Guide
https://github.com/linux-on-ibm-z/docs/wiki/Building-MariaDB-Connector-ODBC